# Windows system shows wrong amount of RAM?

Tags: windows, memory, netbook, eee-pc

I just got an [ASUS Eee PC 1005HA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asus_Eee_PC#Eee_1000_series) and immediately upgraded it to 2 GB of RAM. However, when I open up the Windows System Dialog, it says there is only .99 GB of RAM. [CPU-Z](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-Z) sees the whole 2 GB though. What's going on here?

The BIOS also reports the correct amount of memory in the system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go into the BIOS and **save** the changes - only then will Windows report the correct amount of RAM.

[image]

*P.S. this is one of the most frequently asked questions over at [eeeuser.com](http://forum.eeeuser.com/viewtopic.php?id=75649) :)*

Comment: Makes me wonder how one can design such a system where this is necessary

Comment: you should be even more surprised that this thing is selling like hot cakes, Johannes. ASUS sold millions od Eee PCs :)

Answer (score 0):

I remember that Windows didn't immediately pick up my RAM upgrades right away. Try rebooting a few times.

Answer (score 0):

This problem should be related to how much ram the BIOS reports to Windows.

What's your BIOS version? Try to update to the newest 0801 from [here](http://www.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=BtksJTDENqfsnuyf&content=download), select WinXP then BIOS 0801.

Comment: you don't have to patch the BIOS! the problem is well known with all Eee PC: when you upgrade the system memory, you must go into the BIOS and save the changes, regardless the BIOS version.